# Laravel eloquent get related model as column_name => value

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a Product table related with Image table, one to many relationship.

How do I get Image records not as array? Instead, return only 1 Image record as column_name: value

This code:

```
$products = $request->user()->products()->orderBy('id', 'desc')->with(['images' => function($query) {
            $query->where('featured', 1)->limit(1);
        }])->get();
```

Is returning data like this :

```
{
        "id": 13,
        "name": "Shoes",
        "price": "3.00",
        "stock": 5,
        "pivot": {
            "user_id": 7,
            "product_id": 13
        },
        "images": [
            {
                "id": 5,
                "file": "5da9d9b493403.png",
                "featured" 1,
                "pivot": {
                    "product_id": 13,
                    "image_id": 5
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How to make it return like this?

```
{
        "id": 13,
        "name": "Shoes",
        "price": "3.00",
        "stock": 5,
        "pivot": {
            "user_id": 7,
            "product_id": 13
        },
        "images": "5da9d9b493403.png"
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd have to do some overriding. Might make more sense to add a `featuredImage`  relationship that returns the image with `->where('featured', '=', 1)`. It would still be an object, which you'd access with `$product->featuredImage->file` in PHP, or `product.featured_image.file` in JS

Answer (score 1):

You can append a custom accessor that gets the first image from the relationship

In the `Product` model

```php
protected $appends = ['images'];

public function getImagesAttribute()
{
    return $this->images()->where('featured', 1)->first()->file;
}

public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Image');
}
```

Then just return the query without eager loading

```php
$products = $request->user()->products()->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I feel like this is a really inefficient approach... If you're not (can't use?) eager loading, and you're running a new query with `$this->images()->...->first();`, this is gonna chew through resources if there's a lot of products. Perfectly fine for a single/small amount of products though.

Comment: True, this falls into the n+1 problem, how would you suggest to solve it?

Comment: Different naming convention; `public function getImageAttribute(){ return $this->images->first(function($image){ return $image->featured == 1; })->file; }`, then you can eager load `images` (so that `$this->images` doesn't do another query), and append `image` instead. You have to do a check if `$this->images->first(...);` actually exists, so `$image = $this->images->first(...); if($image){ return $image->file; } return null;`, but that would allow eager loading and `$product->image` to return expected result.

Answer (score 0):

In the Product model

```
protected $appends = ['images'];

public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Image')->select(['name'])->first();
}
```

select the name only and return first relation